# Flow of a left invariant vector field on a Lie group equipped with left-invariant metric and the group's geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, riemannian-geometry

I think the answer to my question is known to many other people, but I'm still getting confused. Let $G$ be a (possibly infinite dimensional also) Lie group and $g$ be its Lie algebra. Consider the Lie group exponential map $exp:g\to G$ by defining $exp(tX):=\phi_t \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$, where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to G$ is a Lie group homomorphism, and $\phi'(0)=X$.

Equip $g$ with an inner product and hence construct a left-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$.

1) It's NOT necessarily true that $\phi(t)=exp(tX)\in G$ is a Riemannian geodesic in $G$, right?

2) Can we find a condition on $X\in g$ so that $t \mapsto  exp(tX)$is a geodesic in $G$?

3) Suppose we know that $\phi(t)$ is a Riemannian geodesic, then does it imply that the left invariant metric on $G$ is also right-invariant? If yes, what's an outline of proof? If no, what's a counter example where flow defined by exponential map is a geodesic but the metric on the group is not bi-invariant?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Geodesics%2C+Parallel+Transport+%26+One-parameterSubgroups+for+Diffeomorphic+Image+Registration&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) paper.

Answer (score 0):

A great and **complete** answer to your question can be found in Arnold's ''Mathematical methods of classical mechanics'', in Appendix 2, plus a great physical motivation for the answer, from rigid body mechanics. If you read
French, be sure to read Arnold's paper ''Sur la géométrie différentielle des
groupes de Lie de dimension infinie et ses applications à l'hydrodynamique
des fluides parfaits''. -- Salem

Comment: This is essentially a "link only" question, where the link in question here is a reference.